# Why doesn't window management software like Divvy work with Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager, adobe-photoshop, adobe

I use both [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) and [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) to manage my  windows. They work fine with application windows with the exceptions of Adobe Photoshop. They just don't seem to work with Photoshop. Whenever I apply them on Photoshop the window just acts bizarrely.

How may I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out that [slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) works just fine with photoshop.. it's a bit more technical/harder to set up than the other two.. but based on the people i've spoken with.. it's well worth the trouble

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Adobe uses non-standard windows which don't respond to being resized programmatically.

I just tried Slate, but while it can move Adobe windows, it can't resize them.

Comment: Using Photoshop CS3 I tested Moom, and it seems to work although with limited value because it is not aware of Adobe's pallets which often end up overlaying the moved window. Of course, this will vary with which "Screen Mode" you are using.